# Is it possible to load granted authorities and other user information AFTER authentication succeeds when using a UserDetailsService?

Tags: spring-security

I have been able to get a Spring Security based application up and running, and it has been satisfying all my requirements until now.

I do have 1 doubt regarding how `UserDetailsService` is used in Spring Security. I have a custom 'UserDetailsService' implementation, which goes like this -

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<UserDetailsDto> userDetailsByEmail = // Load userDetailsDto from database

        if (!userDetailsByEmail.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username does not exists");
        }

        UserDetailsDto userDetailsDto = userDetailsByEmail.get();

        List<Role> roles = roleService.listByEmail(username);
        List<ModulePermission> modulePermissions = modulePermissionService.listByUserId(userDetailsDto.getId());
        UserType userType = userTypeService.getByUserId(userDetailsDto.getId());

        return new LoggedInUser(userDetailsDto, roles, modulePermissions, userType);
    }
}
```

The class `LoggedInUser` is an extension of Spring Security's `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` class, which goes like this -

```
public class LoggedInUser extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private Long userId;
    private boolean firstLogin;
    private UserType userType;
    private List<ModulePermission> modulePermissions;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String contactNo;

    public LoggedInUser(UserDetailsDto userDetailsDto, List<Role> roles, List<ModulePermission> modulePermissions,
            UserType userType) {

        super(userDetailsDto.getEmail(), userDetailsDto.getPassword(), userDetailsDto.getEnabledStatus().getValue(),
                userDetailsDto.getAccountNonExpiredStatus().getValue(), true,
                userDetailsDto.getAccountNonLockedStatus().getValue(),
                roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        this.modulePermissions = modulePermissions;

        this.userType = userType;
        this.userId = userDetailsDto.getId();
        this.firstLogin = userDetailsDto.getIsFirstLoginStatus().getValue();
        this.firstName = userDetailsDto.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = userDetailsDto.getLastName();
        this.contactNo = userDetailsDto.getContactNo();
    }

    public List<ModulePermission> getModulePermissions() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(modulePermissions);
    }

    public UserType getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public boolean isFirstLogin() {
        return firstLogin;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setFirstLogin(boolean firstLogin) {
        this.firstLogin = firstLogin;
    }
}
```

Now, to configure Spring Security to use my `CustomUserDetailsService`, I do the following in security configuration -

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
    return new CustomUserDetailsService();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher(SuperAdminConstant.UrlConstant.ANT_MATCHER_PATH)
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService())
            .formLogin(// further configuration)
}
```

And this works without any problems.

But notice that in `CustomUserDetailsService`, **several database queries are executed even before the user has been authenticated successfully** (This is because Spring Security has created a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, which loads a `UserDetails` implementation (in my case, `LoggedInUser`), and perform various checks on that object AFTER it has been retrieved from a `UserDetailsService` (in my case , `CustomUserDetailsService`)).

Consider that a user has entered the correct username, but a wrong password. In that case, the high-level authentication flow would be -

1. `CustomUserDetailsService` would be called
2. **First** query is executed to verify username and load user details (`UsernameNotFoundException` is not thrown as username is correct)
3. **Second** query is executed to retrieve the roles
4. **Third** query is executed to retrieve module permissions
5. **Fourth** query is executed to retrieve user types
6. `DaoAuthenticationProvider` checks the password, finds it to be incorrect, and throws a `BadCredentialsException`.

So as can be seen, **total 4 queries are executed EVEN BEFORE authentication process has completed, out of which only 1 is essential at this stage (the first query to verify username).**

One solution to this problem can be to eliminate the use of `UserDetailsService` altogeather, and use a custom `AuthenticationProvider` instead.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        // Customize the authentication logic here, and retrieve 
        // user information only if everything is correct.
    }
}
```

**But going by this approach also means that I have to duplicate code and functionality provided by `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`, which includes checking user account status flags manually (accountNonExpired, accountNonLocked etc.), and throwing exceptions.**

So I was wondering **weather it is possible to perform authentication logic in such a way that user information is retrieved only AFTER authentication succeeds, and most of the authentication logic provided by Spring Security can be resused.**

Any ideas will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: That's not a good idea. Spring Security assures that the time is the same either your user exists or your password is wrong. The reason is, that a hacker should not know, if a username exists. For roles you could implement a lazy wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can write implementation of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LoggedInUser loggedInUser = (LoggedInUser)authentication.getPrincipal();

        List<Role> roles = roleService.listByEmail(username);
        List<ModulePermission> modulePermissions = modulePermissionService.listByUserId(userDetailsDto.getId());
        UserType userType = userTypeService.getByUserId(userDetailsDto.getId());

        // Set roles after authentication succeeds

        loggedInUser.setRoles(roles);
        loggedInUser.setModulePermissions(modulePermissions);
        loggedInUser.setUserType(userType);
    }
}
```

After the authentication succeeds, you can obtain logged in user from security context and set additional properties.

Comment: This indeed seems to be a great solution.But sadly, this solution can work only for module permissions and user type, but not roles. This is because granted authorities need to be present when instantiating the User class, so they can't be left null. One way would be to pass empty list during construction, but we don't have a setter for them to reassign them later. The only solution I see is to create a new object of LoggedInUser in the success handler, and re-populate the security context!

Comment: @plutonium1991: `LoggedInUser` is your own class, so you can add the setter.